# What does よくも色々邪魔ァしてくれたな！ mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, manga, japanese-to-english

Can someone explain to me what よくも色々邪魔ァしてくれたな means in this context?

MC and a girl ran away from a bunch of bandits. But after they've stopped for a while to talk, the bandit leader caught up to them and said this:

> おうおう！　よくも色々邪魔ァしてくれたな！

My guess "Hey hey congrats! You've made quite a lot of hindrances to us!" but I'm not sure

Comment: I'm not sure of the context, but why *congrats*? Other than that your understanding seems fine.

Comment: And i'm not quite understand "ouou !" too , I can understand "oi oi!" in anime means "Hey x2" .I just feel like the bandit leader's being sarcastic ,but i'm not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can’t find a dictionary definition, but おうおう is a rude *Heeey!*. So It means *Heeey, you have caused lots of inconvenience for us*.

If this doesn't solve your question, more contexts would be necessary.

Comment: I think i will add "You had the guts" to your suggestion. And this is all the context,they're running away from the bandits who are chasing them >> the girl appears to be the leader of the town and they're having a battle with the bandits (i'm still continue reading though)

Comment: @casualreader　Another option would be to use *How dare you* (a common choice for よくも...したな).